# how I change brackground color of extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I need change background of my grid cell, with my code I change the text color:

```
getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
var grupo = record.get("tipo");
   if (grupo == 'G'){
   console.log('Grupo');
   return 'redUnderlinedText';
}

.redUnderlinedText {
    background-color: blue;// <= this code doesn't work
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[image with my code](http://aplicacoes.sankhya.com.br/temp/text.jpg)

but I would like to change the background of the cell, as shown below.

[I need this](http://aplicacoes.sankhya.com.br/temp/background.jpg)

is this possible?

thanks,
Cláudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough the background you see on a grid is the result of each cell styling.

So this:

```
.x-grid-cell {
    background-color: red;
}
```

should work for all non-selected cells.

In your case I'd try:

```
.redUnderlinedText . x-grid-cell {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```